# Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new' when returning <Component />

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have the code below

```
   <ProtectedRoute path='/u/MyDashboard' component={DashboardPage} />
```

which looks like this

```
export default function ProtectedRoute(props) {

    var [state, statesetter] = useState({ isAuthenticated:false });
    var [dataloaded, loadingsetter] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
       
        statesetter({ isAuthenticated: true });
        loadingsetter(true);
    }, []);

    return (
        dataloaded == true ?
            <Route
                
                render={boo => (
                    state["isAuthenticated"] == true ?
                        <Component  { ...props } /> :
                        <Redirect to={'/login'} />

            )}
            /> :
            <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>

    )}
```

when it return `<component {...props}/>` I get the following error : `Class constructor DashboardPage cannot be invoked without 'new'`. How can I new up the class in the component tag or how can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing converting the `component` prop to `Component` for rendering. Destructure the props object and rename `component`, and spread the rest.

```
export default function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...props }) {
  const [state, statesetter] = useState({ isAuthenticated: false });
  const [dataloaded, loadingsetter] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    statesetter({ isAuthenticated: true });
    loadingsetter(true);
  }, []);

  return dataloaded ? (
    <Route
      render={(routeProps) =>
        state.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  ) : (
    <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
  );
}
```